# Flutter ListView EmptyState with refresh

Tags: flutter

I have a page in my app with a ListView. I'm using a StreamBuilder to receive data. When there is data I build the listview children and the listview is wrapped inside a RefreshIndicator. This is working fine.

Now I want to handle the situation when there is no data aka EmptyState. Be able to display a Container with some content, while still be able to support pull to refresh to force the page/Listview to check for data.

This is how I'm currently doing it

```
return RefreshIndicator(
            key: upcomingRefreshIndicatorKey,
            onRefresh: handleRefresh,
            child: snapshot.hasData ? list : Stack(children: <Widget>[list, emptystate],) ,

        );
```

I'm not sure this is the way to handle EmptyState with ListView, but so far this is the only way I can see to still support refresh when the list is empty. So my main question is how you best handle empty state with LIstView and still supporting PullToRefresh?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To support the [RefreshIndicator](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) inside an empty [ListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) you can set `physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`. This makes the `ListView` always scrolalble. Therefore, we can always trigger the `RefreshIndicator`.

The `Container` you want to display when the `ListView` is empty can be accomplished by two methods:

1. If your data is empty (or null), replace the `ListView` with a [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) with `physics` set to `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`. Then you can place your `Container` as the child of the `SingleChildScrollView`.
2. Instead of replacing the `ListView` you can simply replace the children with your `Container`, given your data is empty (or null).

In the follwing standalone example, I took the second approach:

[image: Demo]

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// dummy stream
StreamController<List<String>> yourStream = StreamController<List<String>>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: refresh,
            child: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
              stream: yourStream.stream,
              builder: (_, snapshot) => ListView(
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), // This makes it always scrollable!
                  children: snapshot.data == null
                      ? [Text('Nothing here :(')]
                      : snapshot.data
                          .map((text) => ListTile(
                                title: Text(text),
                              ))
                          .toList()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> refresh() {
    // dummy code
    yourStream.add(['Quick', 'Brown', 'Fox']);
    return Future.value();
  }
}
```